# Why is Vue not initialized?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Rails application. Sometimes on the pages I place Vue components. It can be as simple dynamic lists. But there can also be a more complex implementation with many components nested in each other.

First, I'll show you how it all works (code).

Part of the code from the main layer in a Rails application:

```
body
  #app
    = yield
```

And part of the code from JS:

```
if (document.getElementById('app')) {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
```

And now about the problem.

Sometimes, when I open the browser, then I loaded the page without Vue components. This issue is equally relevant in macOS Chrome / Safari and iOS Safari. But if I manually reload the page, then everything is fine.

What could be the problem? Why does the browser quickly load a page after launch (probably from a cache?) and reacts poorly to Vue?

Comment: Do you use turbolinks and webpacker ?

Comment: @Sovalina only webpacker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the code when DOM is ready:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your option. Within a few days, see how it will work.